# Go tour #18. How do I pass in integers to Pic?

Tags: go

The following code errors with index out of range. I tried modifying main to 
pic.Show(Pic(500, 500)) but that changes the argument from function to the return type and it fails to compile.  How do I pass in integers if the pic.Show is expecting a function as an argument.

```
package main

import "golang.org/x/tour/pic"

func Pic(dx, dy int) [][]uint8 {

    mypic := [][]uint8{}
    for y := 0; y < dy; y++ {
        mypic[y] = []uint8{}
        for x := 0; x < dx; x++ {
            mypic[y][x] = uint8((x + y) / 2)
        }
    }
    return mypic
}

func main() {
    pic.Show(Pic)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. The Go Tour program will pass `Pic` test values to your program. Your problem is in your code: `panic: runtime error: index out of range`. `[][]uint8{}` and `[]uint8{}` allocate zero `y` and zero `x` slice elements. Use `make` to allocate your `y` and `x` slices. For example,

```
package main

import "golang.org/x/tour/pic"

func Pic(dx, dy int) [][]uint8 {
    pixels := make([][]uint8, dy)
    for y := 0; y < dy; y++ {
        pixels[y] = make([]uint8, dx)
        for x := 0; x < dx; x++ {
            pixels[y][x] = uint8((x + y) / 2)
        }
    }
    return pixels
}

func main() {
    pic.Show(Pic)
}
```

Reference: [Making slices, maps and channels, The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Making_slices_maps_and_channels)

Comment: @Darian311 Something you seem to be asking, but could be more clearly explained:
The reason you can't pass the parameters `pic.Show(Pic(10,10))` is that `pic.Show` expects a  function as parameter.  Thus `pic.Show(Pic)`
You can still call `Pic` directly.   Try `fmt.Println(Pic(3,3))` in `main` and it will print a slice of slices.  e.g. `[[0 5 10] [5 0 15] [10 15 0]]`